# Findinga number in char

Tags: c, text, char

How can I check whether there are numbers in char provided by user in C language?
Last line of C code to change :):

```
char name;
do{
printf("What's your name?\n");
scanf("%s\n", name);
}
\\and here's my pseudocode:
while (name consist of a sign (0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9));
```

Comment: Learn about `strtol`

Comment: Not sure why the down votes.  Question is valid, and clearly presented.

Comment: Downvotes are, because this question is a little bit like - do my homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach that tests for specified chars in one function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100];
    char charset[]= "-+0123456789";
    int len;
    do {
        printf("What's your name?\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        len = strlen(name);
        }
    while (strcspn(name, charset) != len);
    printf ("Your name is '%s'\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `ctype.h` and use the `isdigit()` function.

But you also have another porblems in the posted code, `"%s"` specifier expects a `char` pointer, and you are passing a `char`, may be what you need is a `char` array like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100];
    int i;
    do {
        printf("What's your name?\n");
        scanf("%s\n", name);
    }
    /* and here's my pseudocode: */
    i = 0;
    while ((name[i] != '\0') && 
       ((isdigit(name[i]) != 0) || (name[i] == '-') || (name[i] == '+')))
    {
       /* do something here */
    }
}
```

remember to include `ctype.h` and `stdio.h`

Comment: And what about when I want to check whether my name consists of 'A' letter?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You mean the letter `'A'`?

Comment: @AntoniBąk There is `isalpha()` `isalpanum()` `isspace()`similar such API

Comment: @iharob I think OP wants to check whether the char is alphabet or digit

Answer (score 0):

Use `isdigit();`

Prototype is:

```
int isdigit(int c);
```

Similarly to check the character is alphabet

Use

`isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the string from the user, loop on it to search for correct input.  (i.e. to see if there is a digit embedded in a collection of alpha characters).  Something like this will work:

Assume `userInput` is your string:

```
int i, IsADigit=0;
int len = strlen(userInput);
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    IsADigit |= isdigit(userInput[i]);
}
```

The expression in the loop uses `|=`, which will detect and keep a TRUE value if any of the characters in the string are a digit.

There are many other methods that will work.
***And the following family*** of character tests will allow you to do similar searches for other types of searches etc.:

```
isalnum(.) //alphanumeric test
isalpha(.) //alphabetic test
iscntrl(.) //control char test
isalnum(.) //decimal digit char test
isxdigit(.) //hex digit char test
islower(.) //lowercase char test
```

...***[The list goes on](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Classification-of-Characters.html)***